# toggle() an animate() with jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-animate, jquery

this is a super easy question. I know basically what I want and how to do it, I'm jusy not sure what selector to use in a certain part. The animation works fine if I take away the toggle() function, but it only works to open the menu, not to close it.

Here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu_button').click(function(){
        $(????).toggle(function(){
            $('.sidebar_menu').animate({left:'0'}, 'slow');
            $('.wrapper').animate({'margin-left':'250px'}, 'slow');
        });

    })
});
```

And here is my page code:

```
<div class="sidebar_menu">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <h3>1. Escolher produto</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Entradas</li>
            <li>Peixe</li>
            <li>Saladas</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>2. Preencher dados</h3>
        <h3>3. Finalizar pedido</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <button id="menu_button">menu</button>
            </header>
   </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/**MAIN STYLES**/
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#C00;
}
.sidebar_menu {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #666;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 75%;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 25%;
    background-color:#C00;
}
.menu_button {
    display:none;
    }

    .slideIn {
        background-color: #090;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 50em){
    .sidebar_menu {
        width: 250px;
        left: -250px;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #menu_button {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? It matters because in jQuery 1.9, the way you're toggling was removed. See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @AndrewPeacock, well that just destroys me then. So what is the best practice for 1.9? I was hoping I could do a simple toggle fo the function

Comment: If you're able to use css-transitions, then you could simply `toggleClass()` on two elements. If you are not, then I would suggest looking at adeneo's answer. -- Also, I'm not seeing why you're animating `.sidebar_menu`, the style in `animate()` is the same as the one in the CSS

Comment: The problem with the toggleClass isn't animated. I wanted something a little smoother... And the animate isn't the same as the CSS, becuase it only effects the content on smaller screens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with properly working code: http://jsfiddle.net/6zg7K/1/

You need to add `$('.sidebar_menu').animate({'left':(state ? -250: 0)}, 'slow');` to the code provided by adeneo, so your entire function would be:

```
$('#menu_button').on('click', function(){
    var state = parseInt($('.wrapper').css('margin-left'),10) > 200;
    $('.sidebar_menu').animate({'left':(state ? -250: 0)}, 'slow');
    $('.wrapper').animate({'margin-left': (state ? 0 : 250)}, 'slow');
});
```

This code is a modified version of adeneo's below. All credit for code goes to him.

Comment: Perfect! There's still a bit of a glitch when I resize the browser though, but that's not a problem for what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create some sort of toggling functionality based on the elements left margin :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu_button').on('click', function(){
        var state = parseInt($('.wrapper').css('margin-left'),10) > 200;

        $('.sidebar_menu').animate({left:'0'}, 'slow');

        $('.wrapper').animate({'margin-left': (state ? 0 : 250)}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6zg7K/)

Comment: the first part of the animation works with your code, but the second part of the animation doesn't affect the *.sidebar_menu*, only the .wrapper. Does that mean I have to to Parse a value for the .sidebar_menu?

Comment: You need to add a ternary to that animation as well, thought that much was implied, but Andrew seems to have "borrowed" my code and fixed it for you anyway.

Comment: @adeneo Gave credit to you for code in my answer. Tweaked it because I wanted the question resolved quickly.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock - no problem really, borrow away!