# Open and Close menu jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple menu that opens when you click the button once, then closes the second time,   I did this before but now I can't remember how to do it, I thought this here is the code:

```js
var main = function(){
 $('#menuopen').click(function(){
  $('.leftbox').show();
  $('.leftbox').animate({left: "0"});
  $('.topbox').animate({left: "15%", width: "85%"});
 },
 function(){
  $('.leftbox').animate({left: "-15%"});
  $('.leftbox').hide();
  $('.topbox').animate({left: "0", width: "100%"});
 }
 );
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

h2{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.topbox{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: #006699;
}

.leftbox{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 top: 0px;
 left: -15%;
 width: 15%;
 height: 100%;
 box-shadow: 10px 67px 5px #888888;
}

#commentbox{
 position: absolute;
 top: 87%;
 left: 30%;
 width: 50%;
 resize: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;
}

#submitbox{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #006699;
 left: 82%;
 top: 87%;
 height: 66px;
 width: 132px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 0px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight:;
}

#menuopen{
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 15px;
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="topbox">
  <h2> Name's Lobby </h2>
  <img id="menuopen" src="menu_icon.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="leftbox">
 </div>
 <div class="inputbox">
  <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment!" id="commentbox" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <input id="submitbox" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What here is wrong with this code, isn't the jQuery correct? :O

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618910/toggle-an-animate-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct but create a variable e.g `var open = false;` then do a check when the user clicks the button do something like this `if(open == false){ execute opening })` then `else { execute closing }` because jquery doesn't know whether it's open or not so you've got to do checks on it.

Comment: Thanks, I knew of this way but I thought there was an easier way of doing this.

Comment: There kind of is a easier way but I don't think it's as readable it's the toggle() function.

Comment: Alright, I've done it, it pretty much works perfectly, but, while the animation is closing it, it goes invisible here is the code $('.leftbox').animate({left: "-15%"});
  $('.topbox').animate({left: "0", width: "100%"});
  open = false;
$('.leftbox').hide();

Comment: Ok i'm not too sure but i think it's to do with the .hide() and .show() functions what are the need for those, try and remove them and see what happens.

Comment: I did remove them, and it works, problem is that the shadow is still there, and I want them to be hidden, I don't think it's a proper fix to just remove the shadow xD

Comment: I'm not sure but try on closing move the div back extra then on the opening open it the extra amount, so when it's closed you shouldn't be able to see the shadow maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64137/discussion-between-user3910313-and-george).

Answer (score 1):

@George beat me to it but you can add an `opened` state variable, which gets toggled after each click:

```js
var main = function(){
   var opened = false;
 $('#menuopen').click(function(){
        if (opened) {
    $('.leftbox').animate({left: "-15%"});
    $('.leftbox').hide();
    $('.topbox').animate({left: "0", width: "100%"});
        } else {
    $('.leftbox').show();
    $('.leftbox').animate({left: "0"});
    $('.topbox').animate({left: "15%", width: "85%"});
       }
       opened = !opened;
 });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

h2{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.topbox{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: #006699;
}

.leftbox{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 top: 0px;
 left: -15%;
 width: 15%;
 height: 100%;
 box-shadow: 10px 67px 5px #888888;
}

#commentbox{
 position: absolute;
 top: 87%;
 left: 30%;
 width: 50%;
 resize: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;
}

#submitbox{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #006699;
 left: 82%;
 top: 87%;
 height: 66px;
 width: 132px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 0px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight:;
}

#menuopen{
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 15px;
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="topbox">
  <h2> Name's Lobby </h2>
  <img id="menuopen" src="menu_icon.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="leftbox">
 </div>
 <div class="inputbox">
  <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment!" id="commentbox" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <input id="submitbox" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I receive the same bug as the other answer, while it is closing the leftbox class disappears.